# Is Facebook login suitable for use case which requires silent sign in?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

Currently, we have a use case which requires silent sign in.

In our app, we tend to provide **auto background sync to cloud storage** feature.

User just need to deal with UI login one-time. For rest of the time, he no longer need to deal with UI to sign in explicitly again.

Android app background process will perform silent sign in for him, get the access token, then send the "access token + cloud file" to cloud storage server for authentication and cloud file storage.

We plan to use 3rd party login mechanism like **Google sign-in**, **Facebook login** so that user needs not go through new account creation step.

Such mechanism works pretty well for Google sign-in, as Google provides silent sign in feature.

### Android app which performs Google silent sign in

```
public static GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(WENOTE_CLOUD_STORAGE_CLIENT_ID)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
    return GoogleSignIn.getClient(WeNoteApplication.instance(), signInOptions);
}

GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient();
Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = googleSignInClient.silentSignIn();
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = task.getResult();
    final String idToken = googleSignInAccount.getIdToken();

    // Send idToken to server
}
```

### Back-end code which performs authentication and accept uploaded file

```
@app.route('/upload_file', methods = ['POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']
    user = json.loads(request.form['user'])
    token = user['token']

    # https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth
    try:
        # Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
        idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), constants.CLIENT_ID)

        # Or, if multiple clients access the backend server:
        # idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request())
        # if idinfo['aud'] not in [CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]:
        #     raise ValueError('Could not verify audience.')

        if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
            raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')

        # If auth request is from a G Suite domain:
        # if idinfo['hd'] != GSUITE_DOMAIN_NAME:
        #     raise ValueError('Wrong hosted domain.')

        # ID token is valid. Get the user's Google Account ID from the decoded token.
        sub = idinfo['sub']
```

---

However, I was wondering, is Facebook login ever suitable for such use case? According to

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

> Short-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about an hour or two,
>   while long-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about 60 days.

Does it mean, after 60 days, the access token from Facebook is no longer valid. I need to pop up this UI to user, in order to perform auto background sync to cloud storage?

[image]

The code looks as following for sign in involved pop-up UI. But, how about silent sign in without pop up UI in case access token is expired?

```
private void facebook() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

            // Send accessToken to server.
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        }
    });


    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
            this,
            Arrays.asList("email")
    );
}
```

Is there any way to avoid such UI login as time pass? Or, we should conclude Facebook login is not suitable for use case which requires silent sign in?

Thank you.